# Getting a formula to reference a variable range

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I'm trying to get an equation to work across a variable number of cells. So what I have is a sheet with current costs, and projected costs. I'd like the forecasting number to work off of only the current costs. This is indicated by an ACT at the top of the month. My initial formula of sumifs/countifs was rejected for generating a circular reference error, so I'm wondering if there is a way to have equations dynamically update depending on another cell.

I'd prefer to avoid using dynamic ranges, since we're talking about ~400 lines that need updating, and it's my understanding that ranges need to be added in one at a time.

An example of something that represents what I'd hope the formula would do: =Sum(A1:A(1+B1)), in that the range increases as B1 increases.

A sample data:

```
    Act   Act   Act   Proj   Proj  
A:   1     2     3      2      2
B:   1     3     5      3      3
C:   4     5     6      5      5
```

- Projection A: 2
- Projection B: 3
- Projection C: 5

Then when I add in the actual numbers for the 4th month and change the Proj to Act, the range over which projection A, projection B, etc. calculate off of changes from 3 to 4, without any further input from me.

Comment: To clarify, I'm currently able to do it, but it generates a circular reference error. The powers that be have said there can be no circular reference error message generated.

Comment: `=SUMIF($A$1:$Z$1,"Act",$A2:$Z2)`?  It will only add those that have `Act` in the first row.  You would put this in AA2 and copy/fill down.  You can always change the last column I chose Z arbitrarily.

Comment: This creates a looping error, since the projection then gets wrapped up into the sum, and the projection is based off of the sum. I tried that initially (using an average), but I get the circular reference error, which I'm trying to avoid. I know there isn't actually a circular reference going on, but my goal is to prevent the error message generating in this instance. Simply disabling the error message doesn't work, since I'd still like to know when a circular reference is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET()` to create a reference to an X-by-Y range of columns, e.g.:

`=OFFSET(A1,0,0,10,10)` will create a 10-by-10 reference which refers to `A1:J10`.

You can replace the hardcoded 10's in the formula above by a `COUNTIF()` which infers how many rows and columns the range should refer to.

To avoid a circularity error, you can try defining a Named Range (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) with this formula and using the named range wherever you'd use the formula.

Alternative, you can build a text string with the X-by-Y reference by using `OFFSET()` without the width and height parameters (i.e. the 10's in the formula above), and instead finding the first and last cell in a range. Then wrap those in a `CELL("address",...)` call which will return their address. *(NB: If your starting point is $A$1 you just need to find the ending cell).*

Concatenate these with a `:` in between them and then wrap everything around an `INDIRECT()` wherever you need to use it. In sum, assuming a hardcoded start at `$A$1`:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$1:"&CELL("address",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,COUNTIF(..x-rows..),COUNTIF(..y-cols..))`

*`COUNTIF()` logic for finding the number of rows and columns left as an exercise to the reader*

Comment: That's great! I does what I want... and is still generating a circular reference error.

Comment: I don't believe I'll be able to write the equation without a circular reference error at this point, but thank you!

Comment: @Selkie I'm certain you can, with either Named Ranges or INDIRECT voodoo. See my edit above

Comment: I realized why though - in each cell is a conditional IF act, then DATA, otherwise, PROJ. The otherwise PROJ section will always cause a circular reference error to occur, even though it's looking at the other side of the IF statement. 

In short, the circular part isn't because of the PROJ section, it's because of the ACT section. Your comments are really helpful, and I'll be keeping them in my pocket for when I can better use them!